# How to modify multiple index names in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indices like below,

```
europe_serbia_people
europe_germany_people

etc. (I have a lot of indices)
```

I want to change **all indices** with putting "**old**" keyword to end of indices.

I mean the indices that starts with europe should ends with "**old**"

I have checked **_reindex api** but I don't want to merge my indices , and i can't call this api one by one for all indices cause i have a lot of it.

The expected results should be;

```
europe_serbia_people_old
europe_germany_people_old
```

How can i achieve the expected results ?

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to use the `_reindex` API for this, by using a script that will modify the target index name, like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "europe_*"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dummy"
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._index = ctx._index + '_old'"
  }
}
```

Another way to do it more efficiently is to proceed via snapshots if you have any (or you can create one beforehand). When restoring snapshots, you can [rename the indices you restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-restore-snapshot.html), as follows:

```
POST /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore
{
  "indices": "europe_*",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false,              
  "include_aliases": false,
  "rename_pattern": "(.+)",            <--- capture the full name
  "rename_replacement": "$1_old"       <--- append _old to the original name
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried first one it's worked but there is an issue, the indices that ends with _old, I can only see 1 doc inside of it.  I mean former index has more than 1000 docs but the indices that ends with _old has just 1 doc.

Comment: Are you sure that the ID of the source document is carried out to the target index? Because if they all get the same ID then the same target document is overridden again and again for all source documents

Comment: documents in former indices they all have unique document id and every former indices has more than 1000 of documents but the new indices only store one doc. But i don't know how to handle id via _reindex api.

Comment: Usually, the ID is carried over, so it should also be the case here. Can you share the reindex command you're using and the response you get from it?

Comment: You can run the reindex in the background of course [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57975204/4604579)